# Why don't more people use adblockers?

Tags: bounded-rationality

Economists are fond of posing "puzzles", for example the "annuity puzzle" (why don't more people buy annuities).

I wonder if any economists (or other social scientists) have, in similar spirit, studied the "adblock puzzle" (i.e. why don't more people use adblockers)?

---

Some charts from eMarketer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don’t think this is really a puzzle or has anything to do with bounded rationality. Many internet users might not be simply computer savvy enough to even know about it, think of older generations - that would be information asymmetry. I think if you would compare these statistics with a statistics of people who know about ad blockers you would see overlap. Also, value of ad blocker is pretty low if you frequent only more legitimate sites because most of them don’t really spam you with adds or pop-ups. If someone does not have problem with them it’s not rational to waste time installing it

Comment: Perhaps they simply don't care enough to seek a solution to the problem? This also seems to answer the annuity puzzle.

Comment: @1muflon1: I should clarify that I do not necessarily believe this has anything to do with bounded rationality--it's just that this was the only tag I could find that was even somewhat related. (I was looking for tags like "internet", but couldn't find any such.)